# Prove that in $L^p (X, \mathcal{B}, \mu)$, $f = \sum_{j=1}^k (c_j * \mathbf{1}_{E_j})$ are tense (given, that $\forall_j \: \mu(E_j) < \infty$)

Tags: operator-theory, lp-spaces, monotone-operator-theory

First of all: What does it mean that a function is dense? I know what a dense set is, but what's a dense *function*?

---

**Proof for f $\ge$ 0, for the rest it's analogical**

Let's say, that $E_k = f^{-1} \text{[} k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n})$

For the proof, we use the Monotone Convergence Theorem.

If $\phi_n = \sum_{k}^{n2^n} (\frac{k}{2^n}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{E_k}+ n\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ x \: : \: f(x) > n \right\}})$, then we have: $$\int |f|^p \ge \int |f - \phi_n|^p \rightarrow 0$$

---

What I don't understand is how does this prove that our function $f$ is dense? It just proves that the integral of f taken to the p-th power is greater/equal than 0. Nothing more.

Also, why do we define our $E_k$ in such a specific way? What if they're not like that? Would the prove still hold?

Answer (score 3):

The statement is : the set of simple functions is dense in $L^p$. The proof you gave shows the case $p = 1$. In fact the proof is:

Assume $f \in L^1$ is non negative. Then set
$$
\phi_n = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \frac{k}{2^n}\cdot\mathbf{1}_{E_k} \right)+ n\cdot\mathbf{1}_{\left\{ x \: : \: f(x) > n \right\}}
$$
which is a non-decreasing sequence of positive simple functions with pointwise limit $f$. By the monotone convergence theorem (Beppo-Levi lemma) you have that
$$
\int_X \phi_n d \mu \rightarrow \int_X f d\mu
$$
and thus
$$
||f-\phi_n||_{L^1} = \int_X |f-\phi_n|d\mu = \int_Xfd\mu - \int_X \phi_nd\mu \rightarrow0.
$$

The $E_k$ are taken is such a way that they partition $X$, on each $E_k$ $\phi_n$ approaches $f$ by taking one of its value and the size of each $E_k$ goes to 0. Hence $\phi_n$ approaches $f$.

Of course if you choose randomly your $E_k$ your sequence have no chance to approach $f$. For instance take $E_k = \emptyset$ and $f \neq 0$.

Comment: But how does this prove that $f$ is a dense function i.e. the set of simple functions in $L^p$ is dense?

Comment: Do you agree that I showed that any non negative $f \in L^1$ is the limit in $L^1$ of a sequence of simple functions?

Comment: Yes, but why should this mean that the set of simple functions in $L^p$ is dense? Is it because $\overline{\text{simple functions}} = L^p$, right? But where do we consider the set of simple functions as a closed set?

Comment: What is a dense susbset for you? And do you know the sequential characterization of dense susbet in metric space?

Comment: Let $A \subset X$. Set $A$ is dense $\Leftrightarrow$ $\overline{A} = X$. "And do you know the sequential characterization of dense susbet in metric space?" No

Comment: In a metric space the topological closure and the sequential closure are equal : $A$ is dense if and only if for any $x \in X$ there exists a sequence of points of $A$ with limit $x$.